# Name keys within array from WordPress meta fields

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i am trying to code a calendar script within wordpress and custom post types. works fine so far. I use several custom fields (ACF) to call my desired parameters (event title, start_date, end_date, etc.)

I call the results by `get_posts()`.

but I have a problem with naming my keys within the array. after the foreach operation I can get the desired values e.g. `event_title` by typing `$posts[0]` or start_date by `$posts['1']`.

how can I achieve that I can name the keys so that I can use `$posts[title]` or `$posts['start_date']` in my output?

I have tried to build a second array an use array_combine, but this fails.

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'cpt_kalender', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'numberposts' => '-1', 'meta_key' => 'cf_termin_start', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC' );

$posts = get_posts( $args );

$group_posts = array();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

    /*
        Hole die Termine der einzelnen Startdaten
        - Schreibe das Datumsformat yyyymmdd in yyyy-mm-dd um
    */
    $titel = get_the_title();
    $termin_datum_start = get_field('cf_termin_start');
    $termin_datum_start = new DateTime($termin_datum_start);
    $termin_datum_ende = get_field('cf_termin_ende');
    $termin_datum_ende = new DateTime($termin_datum_ende);      
    $termin_jahr = $termin_datum_start->format('Y');
    $termin_monat = $termin_datum_start->format('F');
    $termin_tag = $termin_datum_start->format('d');
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $termin_start_uhrzeit_stunde = get_field('cf_termin_start_uhrzeit_stunde');
    $termin_start_uhrzeit_minute = get_field('cf_termin_start_uhrzeit_minute');
    $termin_ende_uhrzeit_stunde = get_field('cf_termin_ende_uhrzeit_stunde');       
    $termin_ende_uhrzeit_minute = get_field('cf_termin_ende_uhrzeit_minute');
    $termin_schulfrei = get_field('cf_termin_schulfrei');       
    $termin_intern = get_field('cf_termin_intern');

    /*
        Fülle das Array mit den Werten
    */
    $group_posts[$termin_jahr][$termin_monat][] = array(
        $titel,
        $termin_datum_start,
        $termin_datum_ende, 
        $post_id,
        $termin_start_uhrzeit_stunde,
        $termin_start_uhrzeit_minute,
        $termin_ende_uhrzeit_stunde,
        $termin_ende_uhrzeit_minute,
        $termin_schulfrei,
        $termin_intern
    );

endforeach; ?>
```

Is there any way to tell the array listed above the desired key names in the same foreach operation?

i am thankful for every hint. thx a lot. I am just learning php and this drives me nuts. :(

Comment: You can make a copy of get_posts function with different name and then modify it.

Comment: I don‘t unterstand that. Can you give a short example?

Comment: It's difficult to piblish an example, because you didn't publish this function. You can call get_post1 function, but first you should add this new function based on existed get_post function. In a new function you can add these required keys to the array returned.

Comment: Thank you, @toor. I now know what you meant. The solution below did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part where you are adding the values to the `$group_posts` array. You can add keys to each item.

```
$group_posts[$termin_jahr][$termin_monat][] = array(
  'title'                         => $titel,
  'termin_datum_start'            => $termin_datum_start,
  'termin_datum_ende'             => $termin_datum_ende, 
  'post_id'                       => $post_id,
  'termin_start_uhrzeit_stunde'   => $termin_start_uhrzeit_stunde,
  'termin_start_uhrzeit_minute'   => $termin_start_uhrzeit_minute,
  'termin_ende_uhrzeit_stunde'    => $termin_ende_uhrzeit_stunde,
  'termin_ende_uhrzeit_minute'    => $termin_ende_uhrzeit_minute,
  'termin_schulfrei'              => $termin_schulfrei,
  'termin_intern'                 => $termin_intern
);
```

Then you can access a value like `$group_posts['termin_jahr']['termin_monat']['title']`

Since you are adding each item with `termin_jahr` and `termin_monat` You will need to provide those first to access the correct item's title.

Alternatively you can just add those variables inside of the array and access it later like below:

```
$group_posts = array(
  'title'                         => $titel,
  'termin_datum_start'            => $termin_datum_start,
  'termin_datum_ende'             => $termin_datum_ende, 
  'post_id'                       => $post_id,
  'termin_start_uhrzeit_stunde'   => $termin_start_uhrzeit_stunde,
  'termin_start_uhrzeit_minute'   => $termin_start_uhrzeit_minute,
  'termin_ende_uhrzeit_stunde'    => $termin_ende_uhrzeit_stunde,
  'termin_ende_uhrzeit_minute'    => $termin_ende_uhrzeit_minute,
  'termin_schulfrei'              => $termin_schulfrei,
  'termin_intern'                 => $termin_intern,
  'termin_jahr'                   => $termin_jahr,
  'termin_monat'                  => $termin_monat,
);
```

You can do a `foreach` loop on the `$group_posts` array and then access each item like below:

```
foreach($group_posts as $group_post) {
  // Outputs $titel variable which you added to array above
  echo $group_post['title'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so... much! It works like a charm! The whole time I tried $titel => 'titel' and this way it didn't work. So I guess I first have to name the key?

Comment: No problem, yes its key and then value